# writing text area in python, implementing sockets

Tags: python, sockets, textarea, tkinter

I am doing a simulation of a print server in python, files are sent using sockets to a server which has to be placed in a printer queue. When the client initiates communication with the server must provide an ID (user) and PASSWORD, which will be checked against a list on the server can be verified in a file "passwordlist.txt" which has the following format:

```
akira Aaron
alazrea Ababa
alexander Abbott
andy Abe
andycapp Abel
anxieties Abelian
anxiety Abelson
bailey Aberdeen
batman robin
bd Abidjan
```

Both programs must have a graphical interface on the display:
* Client: user field, password, file to send to print and disconnect from the server.
* Server: A list of files that are queued for printing
On the server should be displayed a list of files that have been properly sent to the queue for printing.

For this I decided to use a "text area" but I have a problem, only shows me the first file in the command to print text area, when the client terminates the connection and if another client tries to connect to the server just crash the program does and does absolutely nothing. What am I doing wrong? I think the problem is that i'm putting part of the instruction code "root.mainloop ()", i have this doubt. how can resolve this failure? im stuck With This..thanks to all

Here's the Client Code:

```
#! /python26/python.exe
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import * 
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
import Tkinter
import sys
import socket
import tkMessageBox

flag = False
class Exit_Button(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        self.widget1()

def salir():
    root.destroy()

def adjuntar_imprimir():
    global flag
    if (flag==False):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "You must login") 
        salir ()
    else:
    # get filename

        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**file_opt)
    # open file on your own
        if filename:
            s.send (filename)
            f= open(filename, 'rb')
            l = f.read(1024)
            while (l):
                s.send(l)
                l = f.read(512)



def iniciar_sesion():
    global flag
    #invoco  el metodo connect del socket pasando como parametro la tupla IP , puerto 
    login = value.get()
    password = value_2.get()
    if ((len(login) == 0) or (len(password)) == 0):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "insert correct login and password") 
        salir ()
    else:
        s.send(login)
        s.send(password)
        recibido = s.recv(1024)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Notify", recibido)
        if (recibido=="Error Check user & Password"):
            salir ()
        else:
            flag = True

##@@--------------------------------------------------------------------------------@@##    

root = Tk() 
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost",  9999))  
# define options for opening or saving a file
file_opt = options = {}
options['defaultextension'] = '' # couldn't figure out how this works
options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('text files', '.txt')]
options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
options['initialfile'] = 'myfile.txt'
options['parent'] = root
options['title'] = 'This is a title'


frame = Frame(root) 
frame.pack(side=LEFT) 
frame.master.title("Servicio de impresion")
value = StringVar()
value_2 = StringVar()

w =  Label(root, text="User Name", fg="red")
w.pack(side = LEFT)
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=value_2, bd =5, show="*")
entry_1.pack(side = RIGHT)


z=  Label(root, text="Password", fg="red")
z.pack(side = RIGHT)
entry_0 = Entry(root, textvariable=value, bd =5)
entry_0.pack(side = RIGHT)

##---------------login----------------
button_0= Button (frame,  text = "login",  command= iniciar_sesion, bg='black', foreground ="red") 
button_0.pack()

##--------------Attach and print File------------
button_3 = Button (frame, text= "print", command=adjuntar_imprimir, bg='black',foreground ="red")
button_3.pack(side=LEFT)


##-----------------Exit------------------------
button_1 = Button(frame, text= "exit", command=salir, bg='black', foreground ="red") 
button_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The Server Code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
import Tkinter
import sys
import socket
import tkMessageBox
def onclick():
   pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Print Server")
text = Text(root, width=60, height=30)
text.pack()

s = socket.socket()

s.bind(("localhost",  9999))
s.listen(100)
i=0

while (True):

    sc, address = s.accept()
    print "Connection from: ", address
    recibido1 = sc.recv(1024)
    recibido2 = sc.recv(1024)
    print  "login:", recibido1, "password:",  recibido2
    salida = (str(recibido1)+" "+str(recibido2)+"\n")
    archivo = open("passwordlist.txt", "r") 
    while True:
        linea = archivo.readline()  #Leo del archivo
        if (salida==linea):
            log_ok ="login ok"
            sc.send(log_ok)      
            break
        if (len(linea))==0:
            error= "Error Check user & Password"
            sc.send(error)
            break
    f = open('print_'+ str(i)+".pdf",'wb') #abierto en escritura binaria
    i=i+1   
# recibimos y escribimos en el fichero
    nombre_archivo = sc.recv(1024)
    cadena = "On Impresion Queue.."+nombre_archivo+"\n"
    text.insert(INSERT, cadena)
    print "On impresion Queue.."+nombre_archivo
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        f.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        if not l: 
            notification= "Complete transfer"
            sc.send(notification)
            break
    f.close() 
    sc.close()
    root.mainloop()
s.close()
```

The program does not tell me any error just when another client tries to login, the client interface is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it crashes, but I know why only one client can connect. Your server just isn't designed to handle multiple clients. When one client connects, all the server does is listen to that client - any other client trying to connect is simply ignored.

The solution is simple: Multithreading. Spawn a new thread for each connecting client, and let the "main" thread accept new connections.

The resulting "while(True)" loop should look somewhat like this:

```
from threading import Thread
tkinterThread= Thread(target=Tk.mainloop, args=[root])#spawn a new Thread object
tkinterThread.start()#make the thread execute the tkinter mainloop
#please note: I'm not sure if the two lines above actually work; I can't test them because Tkinter won't work for me.

def listenToClient(sc, address):
    recibido1 = sc.recv(1024)
    recibido2 = sc.recv(1024)
    print  "login:", recibido1, "password:",  recibido2
    salida = (str(recibido1)+" "+str(recibido2)+"\n")
    archivo = open("passwordlist.txt", "r") 
    while True:
        linea = archivo.readline()  #Leo del archivo
        if (salida==linea):
            log_ok ="login ok"
            sc.send(log_ok)      
            break
        if (len(linea))==0:
            error= "Error Check user & Password"
            sc.send(error)
            break
    f = open('print_'+ str(i)+".pdf",'wb') #abierto en escritura binaria
    i=i+1   
# recibimos y escribimos en el fichero
    nombre_archivo = sc.recv(1024)
    cadena = "On Impresion Queue.."+nombre_archivo+"\n"
    text.insert(INSERT, cadena)
    print "On impresion Queue.."+nombre_archivo
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        f.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        if not l: 
            notification= "Complete transfer"
            sc.send(notification)
            break
    f.close() 
    sc.close()

while (True):
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print "Connection from: ", address
    clientThread= Thread(target=listenToClient, args=[sc,address])#spawn a new thread object
    clientThread.start()#start the thread; it'll execute the "listenToClient" function, passing it "sc" and "address" as arguments
```

This code will (well, should) spawn a thread that takes care of the GUI, meanwhile it'll accept connection requests from clients and spawn a new thread for every client, which checks the client's username and password, and then keeps listening until the client disconnects.